# .htaccess convert all '+' to '-' in one 301 redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

**Aim**

I want to replace the '+' signs of all URL's and convert them to '-'.  URL's can have any number of '+' in them and can have any number of slashes.  I do not want to rewrite the search page.

**Examples**

The first line of each example is the original URL.  The second is what I want my 301 redirect URL to be.

```
https://domain.co.uk/used+cars
https://domain.co.uk/used-cars

https://domain.co.uk/accessories/car+accessories/ferrari+accessories
https://domain.co.uk/accessories/car-accessories/ferrari-accessories

https://domain.co.uk/accessories/car+repair+supplies/old+cars/even+older+cars
https://domain.co.uk/accessories/car-repair-supplies/old-cars/even-older-cars
```

**So Far**

This code works BUT I can see from Firefox Dev Tools and it actually creates a 301 redirect for every '+' it encounters.  Can this be done in one 301 redirect?

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(.*?)(?:,|\+)+(.+?)\sHTTP [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/search
RewriteRule ^ /%1-%2 [L,NE,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use these 2 rules to replace each `+` with `-`:

```
RewriteEngine On

# executes repeatedly as long as there are multiple + in URI
RewriteRule "^([^+]*)\+([^+]+\+.*)$" $1-$2 [N,DPI]

# executes when there is a single + in URI
RewriteRule "^([^+]*)\+([^+]*)$" /$1-$2 [L,R=301,NE]
```

Make sure you keep these rules before other rules in site root .htaccess and also make sure you test from a new browser.